# Probability of getting pregnant

Tags: probability

My girlfriend is being very adamant that having sex *twice* with a condom each time as opposed to *once* with a single condom will reduce her risk of pregnancy. Her reasoning is, in the first case, you use two condoms, so the probability of failure gets squared, and hence, smaller. I know she is wrong, but I can't convince her with common sense. Can you give her a precise mathematical explanation?

Comment: The way I read your question, course A is once with condom $1$, once with condom $2$, while course B is once with condom $1$.  Is that right?  So after the first half of course A, you've already done all of course B, yes?  So the second half of course A can't wipe out any existing pregnancy, can it?

Comment: Yes, and that's my reasoning as well.

Comment: Well, then, the reasoning given in Aaron Montgomery's answer is the "precise" one, but I'm not sure that it will be convincing if the straightforward one isn't.  Maybe, though.

Comment: My hope was that validating her instinct that something should be squared would be compelling. Torsion, let us know how this all works out, yeah? (If we don't hear from you for a while, we'll assume you're on diaper duty.)

Comment: Yes, it did work out. I actually ended up explaining that if you kept doing it, you get a geometric distribution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something gets squared, but it's the probability of *not* getting pregnant.

Suppose that during each... ahem... *encounter*, the probability of getting pregnant is $p$; consequently, the probability of not getting pregnant is $1-p$. What she presumably wants is to not get pregnant at all; this means not getting pregnant as a result of encounter 1, *and* not getting pregnant as a result of encounter 2. The location of the *and* is the subtle part; it means that the relevant probability is $(1-p)^2$, not $p^2$ (which would be the probability of getting pregnant after the first encounter *and* getting pregnant after the second encounter).

Here's another scenario for her to consider that may make the intuition make more sense: let's say that every time you cross a busy highway, you have a chance of getting hit by a car. So, what's riskier: crossing the highway once, or crossing it twice? If you cross it twice, you need to not get hit the first time *and* not to get hit the second time. This is why it's more dangerous to cross twice than to cross once. Now, just imagine that "getting hit by a car" is replaced with "slipping one past the goalie."

Comment: I oddly enjoyed reading that. ://